# Calling function from while loop causing infinite loop

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I have a MySQLi statement in a function as follows:

```
function getTimeData($time) {
    $con = mysqli_connect("domain:port", "user", "password", "dbname") or die (mysql_error());
    $selectedDate = $_SESSION['date'];

    $prepTimeData = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM `time` WHERE `date`=? AND `time`<=? AND `endTime`>=?");
    $prepTimeData->bind_param("sss", $selectedDate, $time, $time);
    $prepTimeData->execute();
    $getTimeData = $prepTimeData->get_result();

    return $getTimeData;
  }
```

and then a while loop to iterate over all the results:

```
while ($data0800 = getTimeData("0800")->fetch_assoc()) {
?><tr><td><?php $data0800['first_name'];?></td>
<td><?php $data0800['riderage'];?></td>
<td><?php $data0800['ridinglevel'];?></td>
<td><?php $data0800['horse'];?></tr><?php
                      }
```

It causes the table to just grow infinitely large without actually populating what it should. Having the statements outside the function works fine, however.

Comment: `mysql_error()` btw does not fit here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call the following code;

```
while ($data0800 = getTimeData("0800")->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Seems fair enough right? But every time the while loops, the function is called, which means a new query is done, in turn meaning it never reaches the end as the value is reset to the first row it finds, instead of calling the function each time the loop loops, using the following to separate the function call from the loop should make it work as you'd expect, collecting each row in turn;

```
$timedata = getTimeData("0800");
while ($data0800 = $timedata->fetch_assoc()) {
```

This is because you are only calling your function once and storing it's result in the `$timedata` variable, rather than refreshing the query and result set every time you go through the loop

Comment: `fetch_assoc()` is already sorting the results in an array right? `$timedata = getTimeData("0800"); $datas = $timedata->fetch_assoc()` followed by `foreach ($datas as $data){}` is also an option to handle this

Comment: `fetch_assoc()` collects a single row, if the OP wants to use each row in turn (as shown by the code in the loop in question), a `while` works better as it gets each row, one at a time, rather than a field at a time which foreach would, `foreach` would loop the data within the row, and not the rows themselves

Comment: @LewisSmith - happy to help! Glad it resolved your issue :)